# How can I raise an exception from within a Mysql trigger?

Tags: java, mysql, exception, triggers

Please consider my trigger snippet:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
INTO num_rows FROM  courses
WHERE
    course_id = NEW.course_id
        AND maxsize > students_registered;

    IF num_rows < 1 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Testing Custom Fail-Over';
    END IF;
```

For SQLSTATE '45000' , how do I raise a SQLException or any kind of exception in a way that I can throw it in my java logic and handle accordingly?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated even if it means shifting my approach.

Comment: I would imagine Connector/J translates signals into `java.sql.SQLException` automatically. Why don't you try it and see what happens?

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax Of course, that was my first try before asking this question, but the catch resulting from a try expecting the SQL exception is never executed, you mean this could be a mistake on my side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connector/J (the MySQL JDBC driver) automatically converts signals into `java.sql.SQLException` with the specified values for **`SQLSTATE`**, **`MESSAGE_TEXT`** &c. filled in; these exceptions can then be handled as usual.